# Shiny - keeping an object to recall later in server, without using `<<-`?

Tags: r, shiny

I've created a shiny app for classifying images into one of a few options. The idea is to collect data on what, if anything, appears in each of the images.

The app I have works well, but in order to get it working the way I want, I've used the `<<-` call in a few places, to change values in the global environment, such that I can call them again later in the script. I've tried with `<-`, but I get incorrect outputs, and the image (which should update to a new image on each button press) stays the same, implying that the `image.source` variable is not being properly updated. The problem with the global variable approach is that those variables will be changed for all users, meaning that if more than one user is working at the same time, they'll interfere with each other's key variables (correct me if I'm wrong).

I've included (a stripped back version of) the app below, but here's the key section, where I've used `<<-`:

```
# when a button is pressed:
observeEvent( input$Shearwater, {

    # print some data to the output file
    cat( paste0( image.source, ",Shearwater\n" ), file = output.file, append = T )

    # remove the image we just looked at from the file list
    file.list <<- file.list[ file.list != image.source ]

    # get the next image to work on
    image.source <<- file.list[1]

    # and render that next image
    output$image <- renderUI(
        img( src = image.source, width = 600 )
    )
})
```

Here is a stripped back version of my app as it is now, to show what I'm doing (please let me know if there's a way I can minimise this example more; this seems to me as much as I can pare it back without losing the point):

```
library( shiny )

# define the inputs and outputs
file.list <- list.files( path = "www", pattern = ".jpg", ignore.case = T )
output.file <- "classifications.txt"

# check for images already classified, and remove them (to avoid duplicating analysis)
if( file.exists( output.file ) && length( readLines( output.file ) ) > 0 ) {
    already.classified <- try( read.csv( output.file,
                                         header = F,
                                         stringsAsFactors = F ),
                               silent = TRUE )
    if( class( already.classified ) != "try-error" ) {
        already.classified <- unique( already.classified[,1] )
        file.list <- file.list[ !file.list %in% already.classified ]
    }
}

# get the first image to display
image.source <- file.list[1]

ui <- shinyUI( fluidPage(

    titlePanel( "Image classification" ),

    # define multiple submit buttons, one for each classification type
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(

            actionButton( inputId = "Shearwater", label = "Shearwater" ),

            br(),br(),
            actionButton( inputId = "Penguin", label = "Penguin" ),

            br(),br(),
            actionButton( inputId = "Other.bird", label = "Other.bird" )

        ),

        # Display the image
        mainPanel( uiOutput( 'image' ) )
    )
) )


server <- shinyServer( function( input, output, session ) {

    # display the first image to the user
    output$image <- renderUI(
        img( src = image.source, width = 600 )
    )

    # when a button is pressed:
    observeEvent( input$Shearwater, {

        # print some data to the output file
        cat( paste0( image.source, ",Shearwater\n" ), file = output.file, append = T )

        # remove the image we just looked at from the file list
        file.list <<- file.list[ file.list != image.source ]

        # get the next image to work on
        image.source <<- file.list[1]

        # and render that next image
        output$image <- renderUI(
            img( src = image.source, width = 600 )
        )
    })

    # repeat the above for each button type
    observeEvent( input$Penguin, {
        cat( paste0( image.source, ",Penguin\n" ), file = output.file, append = T )
        file.list <<- file.list[ file.list != image.source ]
        image.source <<- file.list[1]
        output$image <- renderUI(
            img( src = image.source, width = 600 )
        )
    })
    observeEvent( input$Other.bird, {
        cat( paste0( image.source, ",Other.bird\n" ), file = output.file, append = T )
        file.list <<- file.list[ file.list != image.source ]
        image.source <<- file.list[1]
        output$image <- renderUI(
            img( src = image.source, width = 600 )
        )
    })


})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

- If you'd like to run the app for yourself, just put a folder named "www" alongside the `app.R` file with a few jpgs in it, and it should run for you.

My question is, how can I get the `image.source` and `file.list` objects to change, and be able to reference them when the user presses a button next, without reverting to changing the variables in the global environment, such that each user maintains their own variables?

Thank you!

Comment: I think `reactiveValues` is all you need http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveValues.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment @PorkChop, I can see how that would allow me to extract an `image.source` from `file.list` on demand, but how can I recall that file name (`image.source`) for output after the user clicks a button?

Comment: The problem in your code (and in your explanations) is that the desired interaction (or the non-interaction) between different users is not clear. Example: if there is no relationship between users classifying images,  move the blocks of code 'define the inputs and outputs' and  'get the first image to display' immediately after the 'server' call: they will be initialised at each  session. The <<- will work as desired as the scope of the variables is defined at session level.  Conversely, if once an image is classified by one user needs to be taken out, you need to use reactiveValues.

Comment: Hi @Enzo, I'm not sure I completely understand. I've been reading [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html) about scoping, and it says "# Modify the shared variable varB. It will be visible in other sessions.... varB <<- varB + 1", which seems to imply the `<<-` operator would change objects in other concurrent sessions.

Comment: @Enzo, to be clear, `file.list` could be shared across users (that would be good, but not entirely necessary), but `image.source` needs to be isolated to a particular user, such that it's defined when an image is loaded, then recalled when the user presses any of the available `actionButton` options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I reply here as there is no limit as in the comments)

Even after your last comment I'm a bit confused on how you plan to:

- whether, once an image has been classified by one user, the image needs to be withdrawn from all the other users or it is withdrawn only for the current user
- how you plan to save output data (not present in the
  code)
- what really needs to be shared among all users and what needs
  to be relative to only one user
- how to stop & how you plan to save output data (presumably writing the results to a file)

Therefor for illustration purpose I will just clarify with the code (only `server` part - if this suits your needs you can easily figure out how to change the rest) one of the alternatives.

I assume that users will need to classify all images (only once).

```
server <- shinyServer( function( input, output, session ) {
#-------------------------------------------------------------
# The following chunk of code will be executed first at the start of each shiny session, 
# i.e. for each user (but to be clear, it will be executed as well if the user will refresh
# the browser, which triggers a new session)

# define the inputs and outputs
file.list <- list.files( path = "www", pattern = ".jpg", ignore.case = T )
output.file <- "classifications.txt"

# check for images already classified, and remove them (to avoid duplicating analysis)
if( file.exists( output.file ) && length( readLines( output.file ) ) > 0 ) {
    already.classified <- try( read.csv( output.file,
                                         header = F,
                                         stringsAsFactors = F ),
                               silent = TRUE )
    if( class( already.classified ) != "try-error" ) {
        already.classified <- unique( already.classified[,1] )
        file.list <- file.list[ !file.list %in% already.classified ]
    }
}

# get the first image to display
image.source <- file.list[1]
    # display the first image to the user
#
# end of the chunk of code
#-------------------------------------------------------------

    output$image <- renderUI(
        img( src = image.source, width = 600 )
    )

    # when a button is pressed:
    observeEvent( input$Shearwater, {

        # print some data to the output file
        cat( paste0( image.source, ",Shearwater\n" ), file = output.file, append = T )

        # remove the image we just looked at from the file list
        file.list <<- file.list[ file.list != image.source ]

        # get the next image to work on
        image.source <<- file.list[1]

        # and render that next image
        output$image <- renderUI(
            img( src = image.source, width = 600 )
        )
    })

    # repeat the above for each button type
    observeEvent( input$Penguin, {
        cat( paste0( image.source, ",Penguin\n" ), file = output.file, append = T )
        file.list <<- file.list[ file.list != image.source ]
        image.source <<- file.list[1]
        output$image <- renderUI(
            img( src = image.source, width = 600 )
        )
    })
    observeEvent( input$Other.bird, {
        cat( paste0( image.source, ",Other.bird\n" ), file = output.file, append = T )
        file.list <<- file.list[ file.list != image.source ]
        image.source <<- file.list[1]
        output$image <- renderUI(
            img( src = image.source, width = 600 )
        )
    })


})
```

As per R scoping rules, each `file.list <<-` assignment within a shiny function call will update the global `file.list` value.
At the same time, as the `file.list` value is not defined outside of the server function, every session (typically corresponding to a user session, unless the user does refresh the browser practically re-starting the session) will re-initialise it.

You can play with this concept deciding what to put in scope to the `server` function call and what to manage outside (i.e. truly globally).
I find this solution preferable when there is no requirement for reactiveValues (which are very useful, but only if you exploit their `reactivity` in some way).

If your requirements are different, please clarify / amend your question and I will amend my answer :)

Comment: Thanks for this effort @Enzo. I can't look closely right now (just arrived at a wedding), but will take a closer look later. To be clear on the output, the `cat` function call in each `observeEvent` is what writes the output. On each button press, a new line is added to the predefined text file.

Comment: this works well, so I'm just trying to see what it is that's different here. As you say, the change from my original code is that the initial creation of `file.list` and `image.source` is moved inside the `server` function. I see what you mean in the scoping rules re definitions inside the function will be session specific, so if I understand correctly, that means that `file.list` and `image.source` will now be altered by `<<-` only for the session in which it's invoked, and other sessions' objects will not be affected? Is that right?

Comment: Excellent information, and exactly what I need to achieve what I'm after, thank you @Enzo. `image.source` definitely needs to be defined inside `server`, but I think I'll probably end up with `file.list` outside of it, such that all users "share" the `file.list`, and each file only gets classified once (or a specified number of times). Thank you again!

Answer (score -1):

A way to do what you want to do is to assign `image.source` (and perhaps more) to be a reactive, and then wrap in an isolate statement. So something like this:

```
image.source <- reactive({
    isolate({output <- file.list[input$Shearwater] })
})

 output$image <- renderUI(
        img( src = image.source(), width = 600 )
```

Apologies, I haven't run this. But the idea is that every time you press the Shearwater button, `input$Shearwater` increases by 1. You can use this to index your image vector.

The reactive allows you to refer to it without making it a global variable.

The isolate means it won't recalculate unless `input$Shearwater` changes (I think)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @T.Holme. I do think you're probably on the right track, but I'm not sure this is what I'm after. For one thing, there are multiple `input$` buttons, meaning that `input$Shearwater` would not be a useful reference value for retrieving a new `image.source`. Second, how would I retrieve the value of `image.source` for writing to the output file without triggering it to update?